# Will the JPG "successor" HEIF/HEIC be supported from "photos" or "files"?

Tags: files, photos

New iOS devices are using HEIF (HEIC) by default. Compared to JPG, HEIF is awesome (half the size and better quality).

PS: A preview from "files" would be perfect.

Comment: I would open a feature request here: https://github.com/elementary/photos/issues (I couldn't find any mention of HEIF or HEIC)
One Interesting aspect is patenting, it's apparently a container, so this depends on the patent of the compression that's used. In regards to preview, this is a relevant issue: https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/234